# IncompatibleClassChangeError ... was expected to be of type direct but instead was found to be of type virtual

Tags: java, lambda, rx-java

I´m working with RxJava and now I´m trying to subscribe to an observable by giving a lambda:

```
observableProvider.stringForKey(CURRENT_DELETED_ID)
    .subscribe(str -> this.elementDeleted(str));
```

The problem is, I get this interesting error:

`The method 'void elementDeleted(String)' was expected to be of type direct but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)`

The function looks like that:

```
private elementDeleted(String elemId) {
    // removing element from some lists
    this.updateView();
}
```

what helps is to set the function `elementDeleted(String)` to public but then I get the same error for calling the function `updateUser`. so to solve this issue I would have to set all functions that are called from that point to public. That cannot be the solution for it.

Even if I try to give a function reference like this:

```
observableProvider.stringForKey(CURRENT_DELETED_ID)
    .subscribe(this::elementDeleted);
```

It didn´t work. And I think then it didn´t even work with a public function.

I hope you can help me.

**EDIT**
Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'

android {

    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    compileSdkVersion 24

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.isthebest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 380
        versionName "0.1.8"

        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project-debug.pro'
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ['armeabi-v7a', 'x86']
            }
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release-aggressive.pro')
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project-release.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ['armeabi-v7a']
            }
        }
        beta {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release-aggressive.pro')
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project-release.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project-beta.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ['armeabi-v7a']
            }
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.functionaljava:functionaljava:4.4'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.6.0-20161009.170155-29'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.20'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.20'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.20'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.20'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.20'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
    compile 'ly.count.android:sdk:16.06.03'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.nulab-inc:zxcvbn:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.30'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.5.2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    apt "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2"

    apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.3'
    provided 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.3'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    testApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
    testProvided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    testCompile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile files('libs/dexguard-runtime.jar')
    compile ':securekeyboard-runtime:@aar'
}

afterEvaluate {
    dexguardRelease.logging.level = 'INFO'
}
```

Comment: please show your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @maxost I added my build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are building for android, so maybe issue is as follows: build set minSdkVersion 21 - android 5 lollipop AND targetCompatibility for java 8 - which is supported (very limited though) starting from sdk 24, thus causing your build problems. You can address this issue three ways:

1)  build for minSdkVersion 24, targeting solid [0.4%](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)
of devices

2) get rid of java 8 features and set source/target compatibility to java 7

3) use java 8 features and build using [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) (with some limitations, present on lib readme)